# chrome select options failing on last item with mouse select

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

*** SORRY, FORGOT TO SAY THIS ONLY HAPPENS WITH CHROME ON WINDOWS (Version 32.0.1700.76 m)

When I run a stripped down select with options (see html and fiddle), in chrome, I can not navigate to the last item with a mouse (arrows yes, mouse now). It seems to work in all other browsers.

I've seen this reported but not clear on what the work around is.

http://jsfiddle.net/nSw65/

```
 <form role="form" method="get" action="xxx.php">
    <select name="dfdf">
        <option value="" selected="selected">*** abcde ***</option>
        <option value="45">aa</option>
        <option value="47">bb</option>
        <option value="49">cc</option>
        <option value="52">dd</option>
        <option value="54">ee</option>
        <option value="56">ff</option>
        <option value="58">gg</option>
        <option value="61">hh</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: I have no problem. What does this have to do with Javascript?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 33 beta on a Mac.

Comment: barmar, I'm wondering if the fix is javascript.  try chrome windows if you can.

Comment: It is a problem of Chrome 32 version check this link----https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334227

Comment: You could use something like the Select2 plugin, which replaces standard select menus with CSS menus.